# If we have more than 1 page to get details of users then how to handle user's data till last submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 3 pages to get details of user and I'm confused what to do with users' temp data

whether

- store in `database` and delete incomplete form data using  scheduler
- store in session for that user
- store in cookies

Comment: What about `Session Variable`.

Comment: With "store in database", you mean in a temporary table, right? There are more possibilities too. Using a transaction springs to mind.

Comment: @MrLister - holding an open connection to the database (whether inside a transaction, or not but to maintain a temp table) would be a horrible way to write a website that's waiting for 3 pages to be filled by a user. Do you only write single user websites?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just musing about which options the OP can consider; some better than others. For instance, I'm not sure using session data is the most stable idea. And I'm not sure what you mean by this "single user websites"...

Comment: @MrLister and damien , my idea is after storing in temp table if submission is completed then transfer entries to main tables and if registration is not complete then scheduler will remove temp entries..

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the requirement. The easiest will be session since clearing the data is not required .net will do it automatically on session-expire.

storing in database and cookie will result in more code. If you want to use the best option go for cookie it will use the least server resources, but the round trip can be costly if there are many cookies. since cookies also get transmitted every time u make a request.

The other options that you can think of is using the view state to persist the data. It will require the most code to accomplish, but will be the best since the data is only be kept till the user is completing the form. you will have to take one page data and pass it to another page in view state and so on.

Comment: if page is redirect other page then how we can use viewstate?

Comment: there is not any straight forwart method but http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages will give you a quick hint, I am using something like this, but if your data is less you can even use querystring.

Answer (score 1):

All of the options you mention are valid in some cases.

I would not go for the cookies option since they are sent along with every request and the data could get too large.

If you want to keep information over sessions the database is your only option. Else wise choose the option you seem best.

Answer (score 1):

**1**.if you use database then this option requires DB trips that is not good and it also effects to your application performance.
**2**.Session will be the best option to store user Temp data.With sessions you can use datatable object and then this datatable is assigned to session variable.
**3**.it creates a problem if some user disable browser's cookies.

Happy coding....